# Design Navigation in Window Application and Navigation two different Data Sources In C#

Tags: c#, datagridview, navigation

I am working on Page Navigation logic in window application.

I have two buttons A and B. Button A is returning data (100 records) in Datatable and binding with datagridview1 and the same with button B but returning (200 records). Records will change according to user inputs. Now I have to navigate all the records and I can Navigate button A data easily.

When I click on button B but I still see button A data on navigation. How Navigation button like Next, Previous, First & Last recognize the Data is coming from button A or button B and navigation accordingly.

Please help I am stuck with this problem..........

Comment: Hi Monika, can you post some code to show how you are binding the two data sources to the DataGridView?

Comment: This is the logic on Next Button -----------   DataTable dtDataForGrid;
if (POS < dtGetAll.Rows.Count-1)
{  POS++; ShowAllDataInTextBoxes(POS, dtGetAll, dt );                                           
                dtDataForGrid = call.GetDataByID(int.Parse(txtID.Text));
                ShowDataInDataGridByID(dtDataForGrid, dt);            }
            else            {                MessageBox.Show("End");
                POS = dtGetAll.Rows.Count - 1;            }

Comment: In datagridview I am getting data from both buttons. How Can I add logic in the Navigation buttons that the data source is coming from Button A or Button B?

Comment: There is to much missing to provide an answer. Without more info, my best guess is to make two (2) `BindingSource`’s, one for each table (bsA, bsB). Then in the “A” button click event, set the grid’s `DataSource` and the navigator’s `BindingSource` to the same “bsA.” Then in the “B” click, set the grid and navigator to the “bsB” `BindingSource.`